# adding .htaccess and .htpasswd files do not restrict access to localhost folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have followed the procedure to the letter and it does not work for me.
The procedure: Create file .htaccess which has the following lines of text.
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile "C:/Apache24/htdocs/protected/.htpasswd"
require valid-user 
Next create file .htpasswd which has a username and encrypted password created by http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/
Next I insert both .ht files into the folder named protected, which is in the folder htdocs. 
When I type in the browser address window http://localhost/protected/ and hit enter I get Index of protected and the list of files in it. It never asks for username or password.

See summary above.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile "C:/Apache24/htdocs/protected/.htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

Comment: It's not related to PHP actually, check for `AllowOverride All` (to use .htaccess) in Virtual Host and/or Directory config. Also, check for `mod_auth_basic` module loaded